# Excel macro to clean up data (delete rows) when frames are incomplete

Tags: excel, delete-row, data-cleaning, vba

I have a spreadsheet with data from 4 sensors that needs to be cleaned up. There are a lot of frames with dropped sensors and I need to delete incomplete frame sets (in other words, delete those frames that don't have data for all 4 sensors).

Column A is the sensor#
Column B is the frame# (framecount never starts at 1).
Column C is x
Column D is y
Column E is z

For a complete frame, Column B will have the same frame# in 4 sequential rows. I want to delete every row that is part of an incomplete frame.

My data looks like this:

1, 3579, x1, y1, z1
2, 3579, x2, y2, z2
7, 3579, x7, y7, z7
8, 3579, x8, y8, z8
1, 3580, x1, y1, z1
2, 3580, x2, y2, z2
7, 3580, x7, y7, z7
8, 3580, x8, y8, z8
1, 3581, x1, y1, z1
2, 3581, x2, y2, z2
7, 3581, x7, y7, z7
8, 3581, x8, y8, z8
1, 3582, x1, y1, z1
2, 3582, x2, y2, z2
7, 3582, x7, y7, z7
8, 3582, x8, y8, z8
***1, 3583, x1, y1, z1

2, 3583, x2, y2, z2

1, 3584, x1, y1, z1

2, 3584, x2, y2, z2

1, 3585, x1, y1, z1

2, 3585, x2, y2, z2***
1, 3586, x1, y1, z1
2, 3586, x2, y2, z2
7, 3586, x7, y7, z7
8, 3586, x8, y8, z8

In the dataset above, I would want to delete the **bold rows** for incomplete frames 3583, 3584 & 3585.

Can anyone help with a macro? I have hundreds of worksheets to process so formulas, fill downs, filtering and copy/pasting would take days. Thanks so much for any assistance you can provide!

I tried this code on an earlier dataset that had 8 sensors (it uses the sensor# instead of the frame#) but it didn't work.

```
sub clean_data()

'determine the number of rows
numrows = 1
Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(numrows, 1).Value > 0
    numrows = numrows + 1
Loop
numrows = numrows - 1

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 14).Value = "Original"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 15).Value = "Cleaned"
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 13).Value = "Row Count:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 14).Value = numrows

'determine the number of frames, the number of entire frames missing, and which entire frames are missing
numframes = 0
numframes = ActiveSheet.Cells(numrows, 4).Value - ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value + 1

j = 4
missingframes = 0
numsensor1 = 0
numsensor2 = 0
numsensor3 = 0
numsensor4 = 0
numsensor5 = 0
numsensor6 = 0
numsensor7 = 0
numsensor8 = 0

For i = 1 To numrows
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value - ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value > 1 Then
        missingframes = missingframes + (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value - ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value) - 1
        'activesheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = activesheet.Cells(i, 4).Value
        'activesheet.Cells(j, 3).Value = (activesheet.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value - activesheet.Cells(i, 4).Value) - 1
        'j = j + 1
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then
        numsensor1 = numsensor1 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 2 Then
        numsensor2 = numsensor2 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 3 Then
        numsensor3 = numsensor3 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 4 Then
        numsensor4 = numsensor4 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 5 Then
        numsensor5 = numsensor5 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 6 Then
        numsensor6 = numsensor6 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 7 Then
        numsensor7 = numsensor7 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 8 Then
        numsensor8 = numsensor8 + 1
    End If

Next i

'activesheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = j

ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 13).Value = "Frame Count:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 14).Value = numframes

ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 13).Value = "Missing Frames:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 14).Value = missingframes

ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 13).Value = "Sensor 1:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 14).Value = numsensor1

ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 13).Value = "Sensor 2:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 14).Value = numsensor2

ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 13).Value = "Sensor 3:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 14).Value = numsensor3

ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 13).Value = "Sensor 4:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 14).Value = numsensor4

ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 13).Value = "Sensor 5:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 14).Value = numsensor5

ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 13).Value = "Sensor 6:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 14).Value = numsensor6

ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 13).Value = "Sensor 7:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 14).Value = numsensor7

ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 13).Value = "Sensor 8:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 14).Value = numsensor8

'practice code for insertion and copy/paste
'activesheet.Cells(10, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown 'practice row insert
'activesheet.Rows(3).Select
'Selection.Copy
'activesheet.Rows(11).Activate
'activesheet.Paste

'find first complete set of sensor data
j = 0
i = 0
Do While i <> numrows
    j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
    If j = 8 And ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 8 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(13, 13).Value = "First Set"
        first_set = i - 7
        ActiveSheet.Cells(13, 14).Value = first_set
        i = numrows
    ElseIf j <> 8 And ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 8 Then
        j = 0
    End If
Loop

'find missing sensors and fill in with data from previous sensor frame
j = 1
i = first_set + 8
k = 0
Do While k = 0

     'check for sensors 1 - 8 in sequence
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = j Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 12).Value = 0
        j = j + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> j Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown 'insert a row to accept copied data
        ActiveSheet.Rows(i - 8).Select 'select previous frame with data for missing sensor and then copy the data
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Activate     'change focus to inserted row and paste in the missing data
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 8, 4) + 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 12).Value = 1
        numrows = numrows + 1
        j = j + 1
    End If

    If j = 9 Then
        j = 1
    End If

    If i = numrows Then
        k = 1
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop

'View cleaned data

missingframes = 0
numsensor1 = 0
numsensor2 = 0
numsensor3 = 0
numsensor4 = 0
numsensor5 = 0
numsensor6 = 0
numsensor7 = 0
numsensor8 = 0

i = 1
l = 0
Do While l = 0

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value - ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value > 1 Then
        k = 1
        j = 0
        Do While j = 0
            ActiveSheet.Cells((i + k - 1), 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown 'insert a row to accept copied data
            ActiveSheet.Rows((i + k - 1) - 7).Select 'select previous frame with data for missing sensor and then copy the data
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Rows(i + k).Activate 'change focus to inserted row and paste in the missing data
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + k, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value + 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + k, 12).Value = 2
            numrows = numrows + 1
            k = k + 1

            If k = 9 Then
                j = 1
            End If

        Loop

    End If

    i = i + 1

    If i = numrows + 1 Then
        l = 1
    End If

Loop


'determine the number of rows
numrows = 1
Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(numrows, 1).Value > 0
    numrows = numrows + 1
Loop
numrows = numrows - 1

'activesheet.Cells(1, 14).Value = "Original"
'activesheet.Cells(1, 15).Value = "Cleaned"
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 13).Value = "Row Count:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 15).Value = numrows

'determine the number of frames, the number of entire frames missing, and which entire frames are missing
numframes = 0
numframes = ActiveSheet.Cells(numrows, 4).Value - ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value + 1

For i = 1 To numrows
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value - ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value > 1 Then
        missingframes = missingframes + (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value - ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value) - 1
   End If
Next i

For i = 1 To numrows
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then
        numsensor1 = numsensor1 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 2 Then
        numsensor2 = numsensor2 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 3 Then
        numsensor3 = numsensor3 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 4 Then
        numsensor4 = numsensor4 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 5 Then
        numsensor5 = numsensor5 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 6 Then
        numsensor6 = numsensor6 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 7 Then
        numsensor7 = numsensor7 + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 8 Then
        numsensor8 = numsensor8 + 1
    End If
Next i

'activesheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = j

'activesheet.Cells(3, 13).Value = "Frame Count:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 15).Value = numframes

'activesheet.Cells(4, 13).Value = "Missing Frames:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 15).Value = missingframes

'activesheet.Cells(5, 13).Value = "Sensor 1:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 15).Value = numsensor1

'activesheet.Cells(6, 13).Value = "Sensor 2:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 15).Value = numsensor2

'activesheet.Cells(7, 13).Value = "Sensor 3:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 15).Value = numsensor3

'activesheet.Cells(8, 13).Value = "Sensor 4:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 15).Value = numsensor4

'activesheet.Cells(9, 13).Value = "Sensor 5:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 15).Value = numsensor5

'activesheet.Cells(10, 13).Value = "Sensor 6:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 15).Value = numsensor6

'activesheet.Cells(11, 13).Value = "Sensor 7:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 15).Value = numsensor7

'activesheet.Cells(12, 13).Value = "Sensor 8:"
ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 15).Value = numsensor8

End Sub
```

I have hundreds of files so I don't want to have to import to Matlab, run the script then export back to excel. But here is Matlab code that worked conceptually (column 4 contained the frame# in this dataset):

```
i=xlsread('33_F_.xlsm');

`i2=[i(:,1) i(:,4) i(:,6:11)];  
i3=[];  
[m,n]= size(i2);  
count=1;  
frame=i2(1,2);  
for j=2:m  
if(count==1)  
    frame=i2(j,2);  
end  
if(i2(j,2)==frame)  
    count=count+1;  
else  
    frame=i2(j,2);  
    count=1;  
    i2(j-count:j-1)=[];  
end  

if(count==4)  
    count=0;  
    i3=[i3;i2(j-3:j,:)];  
end  

end`
```

Comment: What have you tried already? I would start by removing all sensors that have fewer than `SensorCount` entries.  No macro needed for this - just some clever formulas and filtering.

Comment: @rmayer06 I tried to include Matlab code I had used but stackoverflow wouldn't accept the formatting and after 20 tries using control-K, I gave up including it. I have hundreds of worksheets to process so I don't want to import to Matlab, run the script and export again to excel.

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with Matlab but you indicate Excel here. Do you have a list of CSV files you want to import and process in Excel? Or would you rather ask this with a Matlab tag?

Comment: Yikes! The VBA code seems hopelessly complex. I'm going to start from scratch with my concept, then have you explain why it won't work if it doesn't.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't combine all the files together for processing? I can't see how hundreds of data files can be effectively utilized in any sort of meaningful analysis.

Comment: each participant completed tasks using 2 different devices at 3 angles per device. Each task/device/angle was repeated twice. I am conducting statistical analysis and looking at interactions between device and angle. I can't combine the files, I'll lose participant data, device data and/or angle data.

Comment: Not necessarily. You simply add column(s) for the attribute(s) specified by the individual files and insert the value. Makes doing any type of overall analysis much easier (in fact, not sure you could do it without having all the data in one flat file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a column "F" with the formula `=COUNTIF(B:B,B1)` in the first row. Double-click the fill-down button (the bottom-right corner of the cell) to copy the formula for all your data.

Then, click within the table and do `CTRL+A` followed by `CTRL+L` - when it asks if your data has headers, say "no" and it will add column names.  Then, filter by column F for any sensors less than 4, and delete those rows.  Clear the filter and you will be good to go.

**Edit** following commentary/discussion, here is a VBA code that does what you need it to do (tested):

```
Public Sub clean()    
Dim i As Integer
i = 1    
Do    
    Dim a As Integer
    a = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), Cells(i, 2))

    If (a < 4) And Len(Cells(i, 1)) > 0 Then
       Rows(i).Delete
    Else
       i = i + 1
    End If        
Loop While Len(Cells(i, 1)) > 0    
End Sub
```

Comment: If you need a macro to do this (e.g. lots of files) the same logic applies to the Macro, but the `Countif` will instead be computed in the macro for each row.

Comment: I have hundreds of worksheets to process, which were imported from .csv files - that's why I asked about a macro. I understand how to fill down formulas but I'm looking for a single macro (one keyboard shortcut) to delete the incomplete frames.

Comment: Like I said, work the code I wrote into a macro. I'll help you if you get started on the macro yourself.

Comment: Your vba code worked! Thank you! It does take a while (about 1-2 minutes per worksheet, with at least 16,000 rows per sheet) is that to be expected? You've saved me days of sitting at my desk doing repetitive crap. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah I never optimized for speed here. But it works and required minimal effort, so that's ultimately mission accomplished.